# Yii2 select2 widget selected value does not appear when I click edit

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2

This is my form. I have save value when I create but then when I update the value wont appear.

```
$form->field($model, 'unit_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [                           
                                'data' => $getunit,
                                'language' => 'en',
                                'value'=>$model->unit_id,    //cant work
                                'initValueText'=>$model->unit_id    //cant work
                                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select','multiple'=>true,'value'=>$model->unit_id'  //cant work ],
                                'pluginOptions' => [
                                    'allowClear' => true,
                                    'tags'=>true,
                                    'maximumInputLength'=>10,
                                ],
                            ])->label(false)
```

Anyone know why? I search through online but I still cant solve it

Comment: When you save the model, the `unit_id` field gets properly saved?

Comment: @gmc yaya everyhing works fine. Just cant figure out where is the mistakes